Conjecture about Euler quotients related to non-Wieferich numbers $W(n)=\frac{2^n+1}{3}$
For odd natural $n$ define the Euler quotient:
$$ a(n)=\frac{(2^{\phi(n)}-1) \bmod n^2}{n}=\frac{2^{\phi(n)}-1}{n} \bmod n$$
$a(n)=0$ is $n$ being Wieferich number (not necessarily prime).
For odd $n$, define $W(n)=\frac{2^n+1}{3}$. If $W(n)$ is prime,
$n$ is Wagstaff prime.
Conjecture 1 $a(W(n)) \bmod 2=1$ for all odd $n>1$.
Conjecture 2 $a(W(n))$ is nonzero all odd $n>1$.
The Conjecture 1 will imply all $a(W(n))$ are non-zero and thus
$W(n)$ non-Wieferich numbers.
If $n$ is prime all prime factors of $W(n)$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $n$,
and we will get infinite sequence of non-Wieferich numbers
with unbounded smallest prime factor.
Experimentally the conjecture holds for $n$ up to $219$ and factorization for
computing the Euler totient is expensive.
Computing the parity of other sequences gives random parity.
